Distribute C# libraries to client - reference in App
I have the problem, that we have to deploy our app with MS Click Once, but it comes with 800MB on libraries that will never change in the near future. Our Roadwarriors have problems installing this giant binary blob.
So I would like to deploy the known libs to the client with our software distribution system and just reference it in my assembly. I tried so far to put everything into the GAC on a testclient, the result was ok for the first part but it did not find the localatizations which are located in the subfolders "de", "pl" etc. of the libraries.
Lets say I have "libname.printing.dll" then in "de/libname.printing.ressources.dll" is the localization. This is not working with the GAC of course.
So I thought, I have to replicate the filestructure of the framework, copy the files to the same folder and tell VS to not copy the DLL into the output directory. Result: The app is not finding it when trying to load it, even when I put the directory into the %path% variable
How do I have to manipulate the csproj file or app.config, to tell the app "This path on the client libs which you need". They are published into "c:\program files\common<company>".
